# AS3: Car movement speed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm beginer in AS3. I'm working follow a tutorial frogger game, you can view full code at here http://www.makeflashgames.com/tutorialsplus/tutorial-frogger.php. At Function startGame(), I know "speedX" is moving speed of the car in the direction of X. I try to change speedX to speedY, but nothing happen, the car just dose not move. Please help me write a function to moving the car follow X and Y. Or please help me make it clear...Thanks :)

```
public function startGame()
    {           
        timeElapsed = 0;
        totalTimer = 99;
        life = 3;
        p1speedX = 0;
        p1speedY = 0;
        gotoWin = false;
        gotoLose = false;
        standingOnLog = false;
        cars = new Array();
        logs = new Array();
        homes = new Array();
        logsYPos = new Array(115,165,215,265);
        carsYPos = new Array(365,415,465,515);

        setupGame();

        //Spawn Cars
        //Row 1
        for (var i=1; i<=2; i++)
        {
            var newCar = new Car();
            newCar.x = -300 * i;
            newCar.y = carsYPos[0];
            newCar.speedX = 150;
            cars.push(newCar);
            addChild(newCar);
        }

        //Row 2
        for (var i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            var newCar = new Car();
            newCar.x = (170 * i) + 500;
            newCar.y = carsYPos[1];
            newCar.speedX = -5;
            cars.push(newCar);
            addChild(newCar);
        }

        //Row 3
        for (var i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            var newCar = new Car();
            newCar.x = (-220 * i) + 100;
            newCar.y = carsYPos[2];
            newCar.speedX = 8;
            cars.push(newCar);
            addChild(newCar);
        }

        //Row 4
        for (var i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            var newCar = new Car();
            newCar.x = (200 * i) + 350;
            newCar.y = carsYPos[3];
            newCar.speedX = -5;
            cars.push(newCar);
            addChild(newCar);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't move the cars, it just sets their speed.

Look at Part 9, handleGameLogic(), for movement.